# How does sort function work in javascript when we use somthing like a-b (i wanna know whats happening in background)

Tags: javascript, sorting

i am new to programming in javascript and was trying  to understand the sort function, like why do we use subtraction  for sorting example

```
const movies = [
    { title: 'a', year: 2018, rating: 3},
    { title: 'b', year: 2018, rating: 4.7},
    { title: 'c', year: 2018, rating: 5},
    { title: 'd', year: 2017, rating: 6.5}
];


const titles = movies
    .sort((x, y) => x.rating - y.rating )
    .map(m => m.title)

console.log(titles)
```

this code returns the movies in sorted by ascending order  but i dont understand why are subtracting x.rating from y.rating. Like what happening in the background how does subtracting them gives the the ascending order

Comment: please have a look to the documentation: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), where the returns value of the callback reflects the actual order of two items.

Comment: The fact that sorting by the difference in `rating` produces a list in alphabetical order is  just a coincidence here.

Comment: i checked  it and i works fine with different rating values i put the ratings  in ascending order on purpose  i just wanna know when it subtracts does it compare answer with initial value  like does it compare sutracted value always with 3

Answer (score 2):

`x - y` makes perfect sense, because if x is less than y, the return value will be negative. If x is greater than y, the return value will be positive. The contract for sort(a,b) is that a *negative return value* means that a is less than b (comes first in ascending order) and a *positive return value* means a is greater than b (comes after in ascending order). Of course `0` means they are *the same* so they can be in *either order*.

Comment: oh so u r saying  that it sorts based on the value from subtracting the two numbers if thats the case does it subtract each number with 3  ??? cuz that will give the results 1.7, 2, 3.5  and thats the right order

Comment: @naveed No. In sort(a,b) a and b are two distinct elements in the array, and the function is comparing their relative order vis-a-vis each other

Comment: Can you please elaborate i am very confused  like can u please tell me what output does  subtracting the numbers give?

Comment: @naveed I don't now what I can describe it any more clearly